# Can I release Swift implementation of an application over the Xamarin implementation in Apple store?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I developed an application that is currently implemented using Xamarin.iOS.
I've come to a point where I think it's better to rewrite my app using Swift.

My question is, can I release the application rewritten in Swift as a major update of the current application? Is Apple store capable of upgrading the app even if one implementation is written in Xamarin.iOS and the other one in Swift?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Keep in mind that Apple services like iTunes connect are on topic here.  Code level questions are much better suited for stack overflow if you have implementation detail oriented follow up questions to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - the store delivers binary content that it code signs as complete so it doesn’t matter how you got the submission to Apple.

Now, the end user experience could still be a mess if you don’t have a smooth migration plan for app data, settings and what happens when someone restores a backup from 6 months ago onto the new version of the app. Those things are hard to test, possibly difficult to program and not something that was designed into your data model currently.